# How to hide address bar in wp8

Tags: internet-explorer, mobile, web-applications, windows-phone-8, address-bar

I am developing a web app in windows phone 8. And I have pin the web page to my desktop. However, I find no idea how to hide address bar in IE.

```
<meta name="mobileoptimized" content="0" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=480,user-scalable=0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

In short, I want to hide address bar in IE via HTML, JS, CSS or local setting.
My current solution is using the native code to build a web view to display my page.

Comment: I also think you are trying to target IE mobile with the mobileoptimized and that has not shipped in about 3-4 years.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunalely there is no way to hide the address bar in IE mobile on Windows Phone at the moment.

If you really need to show a webpage on fullscreen the only way to do that is writing a native app with a full-screen webbrowser control as you have already described it correctly.

Sorry for the bad news...

Comment: Since this is now a couple of years old, I was wondering if there has been any new development on this with the newer versions of Windows Phone?